# Get DH parameters from URDF

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a URDF file from which I wanted to get the DH parameters for a strange use case. Is there a way to get the DH table from the URDF file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227844/get-dh-parameters-from-urdf/) by [AdityaBhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26120/adityabhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having a look at OpenRave like the answer that F.Brosseau linked to suggests might be worth while, but in general having a tool that generates DH parameters from a URDF is difficult because frame based representations like URDF (and KDL chains) can do things that DH does not support such as having the joint rotate around any axis (rather than always Z) and branching chains.

In fact I think having a tool that works for all chains is impossible, DH is a legacy concept nowadays. Maybe if you explain your use case there is a way to avoid using them?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) on 2018-09-09**:
DH is a legacy concept nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at this answer :

http://answers.ros.org/question/54678/d-h-table-for-youbot/

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1